# Creating animated gif in Java

Tags: java, image, animated-gif

I need to create an animated GIF by using frames in Java. For example, I will create a graphic of a function, and it will change with some parameters. A lot of frames will be created and I need to create GIF with these frames. Where should I start?

Comment: Hi Cihat, you don't need to say thanks, and the way you said it is probably not what you wanted it to mean (use the word "pleasure" with care). Use uppercase "I" if possible, and short sentences. Good luck on stackoverflow (don't forget to Google first).

Comment: Oh yeah, and use often used tags, e.g. [tag:java] would have been an obvious choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this may help:

http://www.javakb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/java-programmer/32892/Help-with-GIF-writer-in-imageio#art5

props to @ax. for the link